# I want it to be disappear media player

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a button that when I click on it starts my Media player, I want it to be disappear when  the media player is still playing and then appears again when the media player has stopped

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    // let's say this is your button and your mediaPlayer
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.my_button)
    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    ...

    // start player on button click, also hide button
    button.setOnClickListener {
        // todo: set up the media to play
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()
        button.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    // when player finishes playing the media, show button again
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
        button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

or, if you are using java, this would be the equivalent code:

```
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.my button);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    ...

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                // todo: set up the media to play
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad to help. In that case please accept my answer. If you don't know how, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers